# How do I say "this gives me the creeps" in German?

Tags: english-to-german

> Dieses Haus daneben gibt uns Gänsehaut = The house next door gives us the creeps.

Comment: Off topic: Dieses + da-word do not combine well, because you are pointing in two different directions (here and there). Better to use the neutral demonstrative "das"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to express *"this gives me the creeps"* in German:

> 1. von etwas eine Gänsehaut bekommen:
>      *Von dem Haus gegenüber bekomme ich eine Gänsehaut*
> 2. sich vor etwas gruseln:
>      *Mich gruselt vor dem Haus gegenüber.*
> 3. bei etwas läuft es mir kalt den Rücken herunter.
>      *Beim Anblick des Hauses gegenüber läuft es mir kalt den Rücken herunter.*